# How to populate ION-SELECT in IONIC4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I want to populate a select with an option already selected and the view only shows like non of the options where selected. i get the object throught an API REST on Symfony. Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

This is what console shows me when i get the object:

```html
Array(2)
0:
    actividad: "Musculacion"
    id: "1"
    nombre: "2 Días"
    __proto__: Object
1:
    actividad: "Musculacion"
    id: "2"
    nombre: "Libre"
    __proto__: Object
```

I tried to make the same with static values and its working just fine. I don't know what im not seeing, maybe the problem is the object or the datatype.

```html
<ion-select name="frecuencia_id" #frecuencia_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="inscripcion.frecuencia_id">
    <ion-select-option value="1">2 Días</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Libre</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

This is my code:

```html
<ion-select name="frecuencia_id" #frecuencia_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="inscripcion.frecuencia_id">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let f of frecuencias" value="{{f.id}}">{{f.nombre}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give one of your options a `selected` attribute. Something like this:

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let f of frecuencias"
  [value]="f.id"
  [selected]="f.id === '1'">
    {{ f.nombre }}
</ion-select-option>
```

Comment: First, thanks for your time. I just tried your solution but not working yet

Comment: Maybe with `"f.id === 1"`? Without the quotes around 1?

Comment: tried too but nothing. Its rare because when i press the combo-box for selecting, the option that my object give me it shows selected on the list but doesn't show in the view when just refreshed